# duplicate requests post to scrapy FormRequest

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I am try to learn how  scrapy `FormRequest` works on website,I have the following scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'go2'
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/jsonajax/results2.php'
        payload = {'api_code': 'C123456'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,formdata=json.dumps(payload),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        #yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,formdata=payload) #dict opbject not allowed ?
    def parse(self,response):
        #print(response.text)
        open_in_browser(response)
```

I can't seem to get to right response,I first tried using dictionary but it didn't work, then I tested with `requests` as following and both my tries works.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/jsonajax/results2.php'
payload={'api_code': 'C123456'}
res = requests.post(url, json=payload)
res2 = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
#res3 = requests.post(url, data=payload) doesn't work
```

`FormRequest` takes in key,value not string which is why `json.dumps()` is throwing an error. My question is How can I get FormRequest (or any scrapy methods) to work on this example i.e get the same results as requests.

I believe `res3 = requests.post(url, data=payload)` is the same as `FormRequest(url,formdata=payload)` which is why it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

According to [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/1.7/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) - dict objects are allowed.

And Your code works
[image: code OK]

**Update (not actual as problem was in request body not in headers)**

I use fiddler debugging proxy and compare requests and responses made by different libraries. 
[image: requests]
[image: scrapy]

 As you can see Scrapy and requests library make request with different headers. If you need to receive tha valid request in scrapy code - you need to modify your headers.

**UPDATE_2**

```
class Test(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'go2'
    def start_requests(self):

        url = 'http://www.webscrapingfordatascience.com/jsonajax/results2.php'
        payload = {'api_code': 'C123456'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,body=json.dumps(payload))

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.text)
        #open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying,but this isn't the correct response.  try the requests method you will see the correct one

Comment: I see. Scrapy an requests sent requests with different headers

Comment: can you provide the code that works, so I can accept answer

Comment: `formdata` - scrapy parse formdata payload into key value data while your website requires just json object as request body - they are not the same

Comment: ok I understand now, and since we are not using formdata, a  simple Request will do it as well

Answer (score 0):

It's a common trap for scrapy users. `FormRequest` is forming urlencoded payload from dict, eg:

```
a = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
urlencode(a)
#Result: 'key2=value2&key1=value1'
```

In your case you should use regular `Request` class with `body=json.dumps(your_dict)`

Comment: yes, it does since no formdata is given no need for FormRequest